Как сохранить точки останова в edb при рестарте исследуемого elf
Недавно перешел с реверса PE файлов на ELF. В винде использовал xdbg отладчик, в линуксе же поставил edb. ASLR на машине отключил (VA сегментов не меняются). При исследовании программы ставлю BP, но после перезапуска исследуемой программы BP слетают. Почему такое может происходить? Что необходимо сделать, чтобы BP сохранялись после перезапуска программы?
